# Getting Information from Google Maps Android App

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to use the turn by turn navigation feature of Google maps for my app. Currently I am just using the following method to start the Google maps app on an android phone.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" 
"saddr="+ latitude + "," + longitude + "&daddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude));
startActivity(intent);
```

For my app I need to keep track of how far the destination is and how much time remains to reach the destination in real time. Is there anyway to communicate with a running Google maps app to get this information? I was thinking of running my app in the background as a service while the Google Maps App was running and in the background I could get info about  distance and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to communicate with a running Google maps app to get this information?

There are no documented or supported means of doing this.

Comment: Is there another way to get info about distance and estimated arrival time in real time using any of google's APIs?

Comment: @anishk25: Not that I am aware of, though I have not gone looking for any.